# Specify who can connect

Tags: permissions, configuration, connection, ftp, vsftpd

I've just installed VSFTPD, which I always liked for its ease of use, but I can't find something... Can anyone give me instructions on how I can specify which IP addresses are allowed to connect?

Basically what I want as a result is this:

- You can only login with the user `robin`, with the correct password.
- You can *read*, but not *write* **anything**.
- Only `192.168.1.7` is allowed to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your /etc/vsftpd.conf so it looks like this:

## For allowing local users to log in:

local_enable=YES

## For limiting the users logging in:

userlist_enable=YES

## For only allowing users in userlist, instead of denying:

userlist_deny=NO

## Defining the userlist file:

userlist_file= /etc/vsftpd.user_list

Add the 'robin' username to the /etc/vsftpd.user_list file.

Add the IP address 192.168.1.7 to your /etc/hosts.allow file so it looks like:

`vsftpd: 192.168.1.7`

Restart vsftpd and you should be good to go.